# VLOOKUP with conditions

Tags: excel

I have an issue at the moment which I'm not able to resolve even with multiple combinations of If and Vlookups. I'm not doing this right.

I have a sheet which has the names of the products and an empty column for the Sl Number. The Sl number needs to be retrieved from Sheet 2 if it matches the value in the adjacent cell of the formula (This I know can be possible with Vlookup). However, I am trying to display the value even if the match is not exact. By that I mean if the product name has all the values as on the sheet 1 but also has additional information in brackets, then the value should still be displayed.

Sheet 1
[image: image description]

```
Formula in A2 - A7 = "=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!B:E, 2, 0)"
```

Sheet 2 
The complete data 
[image: image description]

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

---

Apologies, I'm new here and not sure how this works. So trying to do the right thing but may take some time.

Thanks Frank and Tim. I have another extended question to this.

Is there a way to retrieve the value by ignoring text in brackets on the lookup cell itself?

**For example:**

Sheet 1

```
    Sl Number    Name  
    123454       Cream SPF 30+ 50g 
    **NA**       Bar Chocolate 70g X 6 (Sample)
    234256       Hand Wash 150ml
    26786        Toothpaste - Whitening 110g
```

Sheet 2

```
ID  Name                    Sl number   Manufacturer    Quantity
8   Collagen Essence 10ml   456788          AL              87
9   Hand Wash 150ml         234256          AD              23
10  Bar Chocolate 70g X 6   835424          AU              234
```

Row 2 on Sheet 1 has the name that includes (Sample) and the same product on sheet 2 does not contain the (Sample) for that product. Is there a way I can use lookup in the above scenario?

Thank you

Comment: What you mean "_product name has all the values as on the sheet 1 but also has additional information in brackets_"? Moreover, could you provide some example in text based?

Comment: Edit is in review, we can't make edits right now.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(B2 & "*", Sheet2!B:E, 2, 0)` as long as the "Extra" info is tagged onto the end of the name, and none of your product names is a substring of another product name.

Comment: Thanks Tim - Works beautifully

Comment: Tim's got it right. My method would reach the conclusion in a non-straightforward way. By non-straightforward, more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's comment

> =VLOOKUP(B2 & "*", Sheet2!B:E, 2, 0) as long as the "Extra" info is tagged onto the end of the name, and none of your product names is a
>   substring of another product name. – Tim Williams 53 mins ago

Will get what you are looking for, as for getting rid of text between "(...)" use

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("(",A2),LEFT(A2,FIND("(",A2)-1),A2),A2)
```

To create a new column that will cut out anything that has parentheses "(...)" this presumes that all of your entries has the "(...)" at the end, i.e. far right side.

As you are new, I presume you might be interested in an explanation. I'll explain what Tim and I did. If I am incorrect, anyone is free to edit.

Based on your question, it would appear that you are familiar with Excel but not the site. This said, my understanding of the key difference between your attempt and Tim's was `=VLOOKUP(B2 & "*", Sheet2!B:E, 2, 0)` or specifically `& "*"`. This introduces a Wildcard to the search parameter. So if you typed "Bob" but the actual reference was "Bob's Burger" That "*" would allow ['s Burger] to be included as part of the possible search given that you set vLookup to search for Approximate rather than exact matches. `=VLOOKUP(B2 & "*", Sheet2!B:E, 2, 0)` specifically `, 0)`.

As for my part, IFERROR is effectively an catch-all for errors in IF functions. If there is a error, then X. In this case, if it does not find "(" in the cell, then it will throw an error. Since it is an error, display the original cell.

As for `IF(FIND("(",A2),LEFT(A2,FIND("(",A2)-1),A2)` It asks Excel to look for "(" in the cell A2, if it finds it, then it it counts from the LEFT until it finds the "(" and deletes the text one space to the left of the first "(". Thus removing the "(...)".

Comment: Thanks Frank. I've actually now used a combination of both to get the result I wanted.


`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(FIND(" (",B227),TRIM(LEFT(B227,FIND("(",B227)-1)),B227), 'SAP Data dump'!A:Z, 3, 0), VLOOKUP(IFERROR((LEFT(B227,FIND("(",B227)-1)&"*"), B227&"*"), 'SAP Data dump'!A:Z, 3, 0))`

This works perfectly now :) Thanks a ton for all your help!

Comment: Great to hear, it looks like you ran my part before it parses into Tim's, thereby cutting out the "(...)" part.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote Tim's comment for his contribution and role in your solution.

Comment: Sorry how do I do that?